# Can I stop Azure Container Service for Linux from issuing Docker Pull commands?

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am using an Azure App Service (Linux containers) to host a container application. Unfortunately for me, the App Service periodically issues a new Docker Pull command like this:

```
2018-11-08 18:39:32.512 INFO  - Issuing docker pull: imagename =library/ghost:2.2.4-alpine
```

I don't know why it is issuing this command, and I can't find out how to stop it doing so.

I want to stop it because although the volume on which my container stores data can survive restarts of the container, it doesn't seem to survive rebuilding the container. I suspect that this might be because I'm using the Docker Compose (preview), and the docker compose configuration sets a volume name and associates it with the container.

I currently have 'continuous deployment' toggled 'OFF' in the azure console, and I can't find any setting which seems to control whether or not the underlying app service is issuing the docker pull command.

Unfortunately I can't use the docker single container as the pre-built ghost images don't appear to be set up to store data in a volume outside the container.

I have had no luck in searching the App Service FAQs for information about this behaviour. I'm hoping that I've made a foolish mistake which is easy to fix, and that someone here will have seen this and fixed it themselves.

Comment: is it possible the service is crashing and that's when the pull occurs?

Comment: I don't think that is possible - the service was working perfectly right up to the moment when the app service issued the docker pull request. Nothing in any logs I could find that suggested a problem before that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you will know how to achieve what you want if you know the work process of Azure Web App for Container.

Each time when the Web App starts, no matter you restart it or restart itself because of the timeout, it will check the image if it should update. When you use the public Docker hub image, the update dependent on the Docker hub, not your order.

So the best way for you is to store the image in your private container registries like your own git hub or Azure Container Registry. And give the image a specific tag. This way make sure that if you do not update the image, the web app will do the check when it starts.

Comment: Thanks Charles - I'll get onto a private azure container registry right away! (I had foolishly assumed that the docker container I was using was using semantic versioning, and wouldn't be updated with that particular version number. How wrong I was etc etc!

Comment: Nobody can do everything right, so we always have the chance to do the right thing and good luck!